# AsyncQuery with postgresql and dapper using npqsql

Tags: postgresql, c#-4.0, async-await, dapper, npgsql

I was trying dapper orm and recently they added asyncquery support. I googled it about that. It is wonderful if you have heavy traffic on your site. I was trying that with postgressql and dapper. Now, in connection if I am passing simple connection string it works fine. But as per couple of articles it is not true async if I want to use it, I need async connection string.

Now, I don't know how to use with Postgresql and npgsql. Here is complete article for [reference](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asynchronous-database-calls-with-task-based-asynchronous-programming-model-tap-in-asp-net-mvc-4) where author explains how to do it with Sql Server.

What I need to do if I want same with Postgresql?

Please let me know if any further requirement needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of this article is somewhat wrong - in .NET 4.5 the [AsynchronousProcessing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.asynchronousprocessing.aspx) property is ignored because it is no longer required. You can just start [calling the Async methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418.aspx) of SqlClient without any special connection strings.

Whether the operations will execute asynchronously, depends on the database provider. For example, the default implementation of [DbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executedbdatareaderasync.aspx) actually executes synchronously and blocks the calling thread. SqlCommand overrides this method and executes asynchronously.

Unfortunately, NpgsqlCommand doesn't override this method so you are left with synchronous execution only.

Comment: Does this still apply, it seems that they have an async version now https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/main/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlCommand.cs/#L1105