# Does Npgsql support async?

Tags: dapper, npgsql

From this question it seems that Npgsql doesn't support async so I start to replace all my calls by synchronous ones, but the answer is very old and I would like to know if it still applies [AsyncQuery with postgresql and dapper using npqsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938785/asyncquery-with-postgresql-and-dapper-using-npqsql)

This is how most of my code looks like

```
using Dapper;

using(var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var myResult = connection.QueryAsync<MyModel>(
         "SELECT * FROM my_model_table WHERE id = @id"), new { id });
}
```

Comment: From the source [here](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/main/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlCommand.cs/#L1103) it seems it has been fixed in NpgSqlCommand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, recent versions of Npgsql are fully asynchronous. Calling async ADO.NET APIs will properly perform async network operations.

Comment: It should be noted that while Npgsql implements `async` methods, it is does not allow `asynchronous` command execution within the same connection.

Comment: Concurrent use of the same connection indeed isn't allowed (i.e. connection isn't thread-safe), regardless of whether I/O is being done synchronously or asynchronously.